# How do I parse Json with Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-2007

need to parse the following JSON but can't figure out how to do it with D2007 and uJSON
can someone show me a examble how I can access this values?

```
{
    "id": "40",
    "created_at": "2013-08-02 20:50:28",
    "delivery_at": "2013-08-02 20:50:28",
    "cid": "7",
    "firstname": "Joe",
    "lastname": "Average",
    "street": "Joes Place",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 601,
            "price": 25,
            "name": "Pizza Party 40x60 cm",
            "qty": 1,
            "opt": 8,
            "extras": [
                [
                    "Salmon",
                    0
                ],
                [
                    "Spinach",
                    1.5
                ],

            ]
        }
    ],
    "eMail": "me@examble.com"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

edit: corrected wrong json (maybe not totally wrong, but not intended)

Comment: You can have a look at [SuperObject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/) and the examples as an alternative to uJson

Comment: Your json is invalid. Items nested value is a string and not a valid json array...

Comment: That doesn't make it invalid JSON, @Arnaud. It's entirely possible for one of the string values to *happen* to contain something that could itself be interpreted as more JSON. Whether JSON strings are allowed to contain line breaks is another matter, though.

Comment: Op did fix its json. And line breaks should be escaped, as stated by the specs..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Sir Rufo i tried it with SuperObject and I could get it to work.
Here my solution hopefully it will help others. don't know if it the shortest way but it works.

But if you can write some shorter code feel free to edit this answer. (also if you can correct my poor English ;)

```
var
   order, pos: ISuperObject;
   firstname, lastname, street, created_at, delivery_at, cid, eMail : String;
   id, i : Integer;
begin

       order := SO(<jsontext>);

       id := order.AsObject.I['id'];
       fistname := order.AsObject.S['firstname'];
       lastname := order.AsObject.S['lastname'];
       street := order.AsObject.S['street'];
       cid := order.AsObject.S['cid'];
       eMail := order.AsObject.S['eMail'];
       created_at := order.AsObject.S['created_at'];
       delivery_at := order.AsObject.S['delivery_at'];

       // do some stuff with your values
       // and next are the articles of our pizza order ;)
       for pos in order['items'] do begin

           // get the values like this
           ShowMessage(pos['name'].AsString)
       end;

       // and now the array of extra ingredients for an particular article

       for i := 0 to pos['extras'].AsArray.Length - 1 do begin

            // do some stuff here we Show it again only for demonstration purpose
            ShowMessage(pos['extras[' + IntToStr(i) + '][0]'].AsString)
       end

end;
```

Comment: What is the reason for your last edit? Are you still looking for an answer? To what question? If you have a question feel free to post a new one or update this, but don't expect anyone to answer an answer

Comment: no, sorry everything ok